# Tensorflow - adding Dropout layer increases inference time significantly

Tags: performance, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have relatively small CNN

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(input_shape=(400,400,3), filters=6, kernel_size=5, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=12, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=24, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='valid', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='valid', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=48, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='valid', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='valid', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=96, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='valid', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='valid', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(240, activation='softmax')
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
```

I use the following code to measure model performance:

```
for img_per_batch in [1, 5, 10, 50]:
    # warm up the model
    image = np.random.random(size=(img_per_batch, 400, 400, 3)).astype('float32')
    model(image, training=False)

    n_iter = 100
    start_time = time.time()
    for _ in range(n_iter):
        image = np.random.random(size=(img_per_batch, 400, 400, 3)).astype('float32')
        model(image, training=False)
    dt = (time.time() - start_time) * 1000
    print(f'img_per_batch = {img_per_batch}, {dt/n_iter:.2f} ms per iteration, {dt/n_iter/img_per_batch:.2f} ms per image')
```

My output (Nvidia Jetson Xavier, tensorflow==2.0.0):

```
img_per_batch = 1, 21.74 ms per iteration, 21.74 ms per image
img_per_batch = 5, 42.35 ms per iteration, 8.47 ms per image
img_per_batch = 10, 68.37 ms per iteration, 6.84 ms per image
img_per_batch = 50, 312.83 ms per iteration, 6.26 ms per image
```

Then I add dropout layer after each of the fully connected layers:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    # ... convolution layers are same
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.3),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.3),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(.3),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(240, activation='softmax')
])
```

With added layers output becomes as bellow:

```
img_per_batch = 1, 31.18 ms per iteration, 31.18 ms per image
img_per_batch = 5, 76.15 ms per iteration, 15.23 ms per image
img_per_batch = 10, 127.91 ms per iteration, 12.79 ms per image
img_per_batch = 50, 513.85 ms per iteration, 10.28 ms per image
```

In theory dropout layer shouldn't impact inference performance. But in the code above adding dropout layer increase single-image prediction time in 1.5 times and 10-images batch prediction is almost twice slower than without dropout. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Look at the shapes in model.summary(), count how many elements are there and how much work dropout has to do. Your network has almost no downsampling so many layers output a lot of elements.

Comment: The question was not why dropout layer is slow, but why it slow down *inference*. In my understanding dropout layer should be active in training mode only and disabled during prediction (when passing training=False). And the output of the Flatten layer has the shape (None, 3200), it is not a lot of params for dropout layer and cannot explain twofold performance decrease (every convolutional layer has strides=2, so network does have downsampling)

Comment: I agree what this doesn't make any sense. but whatever is going wromng here it's clearly fixed in tf2.2: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1HGflFrHUH4vtL9Uc1un1lYLlhnMbuvva

Comment: Well, technically at inference time you should still multiply the layer inputs by `p_keep` to preserve the shape of the training distributions, right? Perhaps this could explain the difference

Answer (score 5):

Apparently this is a known problem in TensorFlow 2.0.0: [see this GitHub comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33487#issuecomment-589441736).

Try to use `model.predict(x)` instead of `model(x)`.

This can also be fixed by updating to a more recent version of TensorFlow like 2.1.0.

Hope this helps